# Throw an exception while doing dataframe sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one of the row is filled with string "Error"

I am trying to add rows of 2 different dataframe. However, since I have the string in one of the row, it is concatenating the 2 strings.

So, I am having the dataframe filled with a row "ErrorError". I would prefer leaving this row empty than concatenating the strings.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks
kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix resulting DataFrame using `df.replace({'FieldName': {'ErrorError': ''}})`

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot, I did precisely that. Only difference being,   I replaced the df (error)  with None to begin with. Thank you so much for your time and help